# Canvas, Квадрат движется быстрее, если двигать мышкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

Нужно было реализовать движение квадрата. Я сделал, вот только движется он очень медленно, а если двигать мышкой, то нормально. Объясните пожалуйста почему так происходит?

```
from tkinter import *

def funkcia():
    c.move(kvadrat, 1, 0.22)
    if c.coords(kvadrat)[2] < 1000:
        root.after(3, funkcia)

    if c.coords(kvadrat)[2] == 200:
        c.itemconfigure(kvadrat, fill="red")
    elif c.coords(kvadrat)[2] == 400:
        c.itemconfigure(kvadrat, fill="green")
    elif c.coords(kvadrat)[2] == 600:
        c.itemconfigure(kvadrat, fill="yellow")
    elif c.coords(kvadrat)[2] == 800:
        c.itemconfigure(kvadrat, fill="purple")
    elif c.coords(kvadrat)[2] == 1000:
        c.itemconfigure(kvadrat, fill="orange")

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(width=1000, height=500, bg='grey80')
c.pack()
kvadrat = c.create_rectangle([5, 200], [105, 300], fill="black")
funkcia()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Таймер Windows не очень хорошо работает с задержками меньше 50 мс. Стоит попробовать с `root.after(50, funkcia)`.